# Django, DRF - returning a list of user permissions in boolean values

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I would like to achieve the following in Django/DRF:

Implement an endpoint which, given the id of an user, returns a list of their permissions. (And by that I mean the models `User` and `Permission` from `django.contrib.auth.models`).

Now, this is quite simple, I can get those using this code below:

```
class UserPermissions(RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = PermissionSerializer

    def get(self, request, pk):
        permissions = User.objects.get(pk=pk).get_all_permissions()
        print User.objects.get(pk=pk).user_permissions
        data = {
            'permissions': permissions
        }
        serializer = PermissionSerializer(data)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And this is the response I get:

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "auth.add_user",
        "auth.add_group",
        "auth.add_userproxy",
        "auth.change_group",
        "auth.change_user",
        "auth.delete_permission",
        "evidence.view_all_customers"
    ]
}
```

However, this is not exactly what I want. I would like to return a list of all the permissions in the system, with a true/false value for each individual permission for a given user.

Naturally, I tried getting the complete list of permissions to compare them against the user's permissions, but this is where I stumbled upon a problem:

The `Permission` model from `django.contrib.auth.models`, from which I can get a complete list of permissions in the system, has the following attributes:

`name`, `content_type` and `codename`. I found that `codename` is the attribute I need, but there's a problem - it contains the name without the prepended app name (for example, just "add_user", instead of "auth.add_user", as returned by `User.get_all_permissions()`.

This basically makes the two incomparable. Is there a way to do this nicely? I only want to resort to substring matching as a last resort, since I don't think it's a good practice.

Edit: as requested, here is an example:

Say that there are, for example, the following permissions in the system:

```
"auth.add_user",
"auth.add_group",
"auth.add_userproxy",
"auth.change_group",
"auth.change_user",
"auth.delete_permission",
"evidence.view_all_customers"
"contenttypes.add_contenttype",
"evidence.view_all_demands",
"evidence.delete_supplier"
```

I want to create an endpoint, which, given an user id, returns the following:

```
{
    "permissions": {
        "auth.add_user" : True,
        "auth.add_group" : True,
        "auth.add_userproxy" : False,
        "auth.change_group" : False,
        "auth.change_user" : True,
        "auth.delete_permission" : False,
        "evidence.view_all_customers" : False,
        "contenttypes.add_contenttype" : True,
        "evidence.view_all_demands" : False,
        "evidence.delete_supplier" : True,
    }
}
```

Comment: could update the question with your input and expected output ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, remember that [super-users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser) have by definition all the permissions, so you can always do (without saving any new user):

```
all_permissions = set(User(is_superuser=True).get_all_permissions())
user_permissions = User.objects.get(pk=pk).get_all_permissions()

return {p: p in user_permissions for p in all_permissions}
```

This will return the dict you want:

```
{
    "auth.add_user": True,
    "auth.add_group": False,
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome, it works, and it does not rely on a super user already saved in the DB, thanks! +1